# How to implement a 'square list' iterator

Tags: c++, list, linked-list

I am using C++ to implement a square list which is a doubly-linked list of doubly-linked lists. The list is sorted, and the idea is that the structure maintains the shape of a square as elements are inserted and erased. If the list has four elements in total that square would be in a 2x2 shape.

It looks something like this:

[image]

I've done some research on linked lists and understand that the general idea is to create nodes that hold each data element, as well as pointers to and from the surrounding elements, but one thing that's throwing me off is how I would (or could) implement an iterator to traverse the square list.

This is my first time attempting to build a data structure, so the process in general is pretty new to me. Any tips appreciated!

Comment: Why would a ``doubly-linked list`` has head-tail connection? This should be stated as ``circular doubly-linked list``. If so, then connection of node 10 and 40 is weird because if has 1 way connection only.

Comment: Can you not build an iterator type for the top-level lists and an iterator type for the second-level lists, and then have another iterator type that iterates both dimensions?

Comment: @Krypton probably so you can iterate it backwards without having to iterate it forwards first.

Comment: Nodes 40, 80, 120, and 160 are missing forward links back to their respective "head nodes". The "head node" is a member of a circular doubly-linked list that has a circular doubly-linked list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few design decisions you need to make, like whether it matters if the overall iteration exhausts each "inner" list in turn, or should return the first elements of all inner lists, then the second etc..

As a taste of how to implement this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

template <typename T>
struct Iterator
{
    typedef typename std::list<std::list<T> >::iterator outer_iterator;
    typedef typename std::list<T>::iterator inner_iterator;

    outer_iterator outer_;
    bool inner_initialised_;
    inner_iterator inner_;

    Iterator(outer_iterator begin)
      : outer_(begin), inner_initialised_(false)
    { }

    T& operator*()
    {
        if (!inner_initialised_)
        {
            inner_ = outer_->begin();
            inner_initialised_ = true;
        }
        return *inner_;
    }

    T& operator->() { return operator*(); }

    Iterator& operator++()
    {
        if (++inner_ == outer_->end())
        {
            ++outer_;
            inner_initialised_ = false;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator!=(outer_iterator i) const { return outer_ != i; }
};

int main()
{
    std::list<std::list<int>> lli;
    std::list<int> li;
    li.push_back(42);
    li.push_back(13);
    lli.push_back(li);
    li.push_back(999);
    lli.push_back(li);
    for (Iterator<int> i = lli.begin(); i != lli.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << *i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
42 13 42 13 999
```

Notice the `bool inner_initialised_` variable - it ensures no attempt is made to call `->begin()` on an outer iterator value equal to `end()`.

You'll probably want to flesh that out a little with `operator==`, `++(int)`, `--`, a `const` version for `const_iterator`s etc. for more general usage.  I'd normally make the custom iterator class a member of the custom container class, providing `begin()` and `end()` that yield custom iterator objects, but I'm not sure if you're planning to have an actual "square list" class or just use `list<list<T>>` everywhere.